# Access shared files on windows server 2008r Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, windows-server

I have installed windows server 2008r on a desktop computer. I have Active Directory running on it. The intention is to access files in the shared folder from other computers on the network.  I have created a group with 5 users in a departmental unit and given them permissions to the folder. The users have logon names and passwords.

i am able to log unto the computer (server) from another computer with the server name and main password for the server.

My challenge is how do the users log into the server from other computers with their logon names and passwords

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure after creating a user in ADUC you can logoff of the server and then log back in with the user you just created. That is locally of course, but if you want to logon to the server from a different computer you should probably setup Remote Desktop Server Role so you users can access it, with the proper permissions of course.